# Image Hotspot in Wordpress with Avada Theme - Hovering issue

Tags: javascript, css, wordpress

I have an Image Hotspot map using wordspace with avada theme with pins that you can hover that bring up some content. I need the content to be shown while I hover the content as well. As soon as I no longer hover the ping, the content disappears. If I click on the point the content stays but I need it to be available without me clicking in it. Anybody has any idea how to fix that?

I'm not sure if I would need some custom js or css to fix this issue.